# Mount an EBS volume to ECS Task

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Use AWS CDK I have an ASG + ECS Cluster & an external EBS Volume created.

```
df -h
/dev/nvme0n1p1   30G  9.6G   21G  32% /
/dev/nvme1n1    200G  237M  200G   1% /mnt
```

*NOTE: The drive is formatted and mounted by UserData, so should be ready to go before any containers start.*

My container starts up using an ENTRYPOINT,

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/sh", "/opt/startup.sh"]
```

The container starts fine using `startup.sh`, but now I want to mount the `/mnt` directory from the host into the container, how can i do that?

On the same server if i run `docker run -p 80:80 -v /mnt:/opt httpd` the `/mnt` directory mounts fine so I need a way to control the ECS task.

Comment: Here is the documentation for that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of completing this is to use a docker volume plugin, here is the CDK code to complete this.

I found this article very helpful

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-ecs-and-docker-volume-drivers-amazon-ebs/

```
    const EBSVolumeName = 'data-volume'
    cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider)
    const taskDefinition = new ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(this, 'TaskDef', {
      volumes:[{ //https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-ecs-and-docker-volume-drivers-amazon-ebs/
        name: EBSVolumeName,
        dockerVolumeConfiguration:{
          autoprovision:true,
          scope: ecs.Scope.SHARED, //a shared volume is for use cases where the volume lifecycle is independent of the ECS task.
          driver: 'rexray/ebs',
          driverOpts:{
            volumetype: 'gp3',
            size:'200',
          }
        }
      }]
    });

const appTask = taskDefinition.addContainer('DefaultContainer', {//define the container})

appTask.addMountPoints({sourceVolume:EBSVolumeName, containerPath: '/mnt', readOnly: false})
```